Gitlab CI job failing despite return 0 - faulty Docker image
I have a Gitlab CI job that is failing, depite last command returning 0. The run of a minimal script (just doing ps -a and echo $?) logs as follows:
$ ps -A
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:00 bash
      9 ?        00:00:00 bash
     19 ?        00:00:00 ps
$ echo $?
0
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I narrowed the issue down to Docker image used - the same job run on the same runner but with another image succeeds as expected.
Here's the Dockerfile (of the problematic image):
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y \
    locales sudo python3 \
    python3-pip python3-pexpect python3-git python3-jinja2 python3-subunit \
    binutils build-essential bzip2 chrpath cpio cpp curl debianutils diffstat \
    file g++ gawk gcc git iputils-ping libacl1 libgnutls28-dev liblz4-tool \
    libtinfo5 make patch socat unzip wget xz-utils zstd zip

RUN locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8" && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

RUN useradd -m bb && \
    usermod -aG sudo bb && \
    mkdir -p /home/bb && \
    chown -R bb:bb /home/bb && \
    usermod --shell /bin/bash bb && \
    echo "bb ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/no_password

ENTRYPOINT exec /bin/bash -l
WORKDIR /home/bb
USER bb

Any idea what might be wrong, or how to debug this further? Running on local runner with --debug doesn't provide any more insight unfortunately.

That ENTRYPOINT line looks suspicious – it sets the container to only be able to run a shell and not any other program, it ignores the CMD the container is given, and ENTRYPOINT is a little annoying to override.  Can you delete that line and set the image's CMD to run the thing the container actually needs to do?

(I'd suggest dramatically cutting down that Debian package list.  Don't install sysadmin tools like unzip, patch, or cpio, low-level network-debugging tools like iputils-ping, or disable basic security controls via sudo.  Install only the specific things your application needs to run.)

@DavidMaze thanks for suggestions. The packages are needed to run the application, which is BitBake (Yocto), they come from documentation. Sudo is convenient for development with the same image - could you please explain why it's a bad idea to have it (or is it just because it's not necessary for "normal" usage)?

@DavidMaze as for the ENTRYPOINT suggestion, that was indeed it, removing it fixes the problem :-) Please add that as an answer so I can accept it (ideally with some explanation, as I still don't understand why it was problematic - especially that I use it in 2 other images that work with Gitlab CI with no issues)

Your bb user has unlimited permissions over the container filesystem, so long as they ask politely; you're gaining fairly little over just running as root.  In a Docker context, in the unusual case you are getting a shell inside the container, you can always docker run -u root or docker exec -u root to change the user ID, without needing sudo in your image.  That seems like a long list of dependencies just to be able to run the application, and as you've shown it the application itself isn't in the image.

You should delete your Dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT line.
You currently have
ENTRYPOINT exec /bin/bash -l

Note that this is a shell-form command (there is no JSON-array syntax), so Docker automatically wraps it in /bin/sh -c.  This is especially problematic, since the CMD is passed as arguments to the entrypoint, but sh -c generally ignores its arguments.  If your automation runs for example
docker run --rm your-image ls /app

then the main container command becomes
/bin/sh -c 'exec /bin/bash -l' ls /app

and the arguments after the sh -c string are visible as positional arguments $0 and $1 inside the string, but they're not executed themselves, unless your ENTRYPOINT value takes care to use it.
It sounds like you might be trying to build a collection of tools, in a way that could be used by some other entity (say, as a Jenkins builder container) without having a specific single application packaged in it.  In this case, you can leave out ENTRYPOINT and CMD entirely; you'll inherit these settings from the base image (which often will still default to running a shell) and expect whatever entity runs the container to provide its own command.
More generally, I'd suggest that, if you do include ENTRYPOINT, it always should use JSON-array syntax, lest you lose any caller-provided command.  I tend to prefer putting the actual command the container is going to run in Dockerfile CMD, and if you do include ENTRYPOINT, make it be a shell script that ends in exec "$@" to run whatever command the container is given.

Thanks - the solution worked, also for the good practices; I will update my images :-)
